# Nested random effects in lme

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a data which is longitudinal. I have same subject reading at 3 different treatment one after the other and I ran the samples in 2 batches:

- Batch one has subject id 1:7 and the three time point for each
- Batch two has id 8:13 and three time point reading for each

I am trying to fit a mixed effect model with two random effects. `X` is my level of substance in blood. `Visit1` is a factor with 3 levels.

```r
lme1 <- lme(fixed = x~visit1, random = ~ visit1|sampleid/batch,data=newx)
```

Since batch is a higher level. Would this be correct? The reason of my confusion is the output:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: newx
       AIC      BIC    logLik
    98.60629 123.9426 -33.30314

Random effects:

 Formula: ~visit1 | sampleid

 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization

            StdDev    Corr         
(Intercept) 0.4653918 (Intr) vst1V4
 visit1V4    0.5036920 -0.475       
 visit1V7    0.2531549 -0.466  0.003

Formula: ~visit1 | batch %in% sampleid
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr         
(Intercept) 0.4653914 (Intr) vst1V4
visit1V4    0.5036924 -0.475       
visit1V7    0.2531550 -0.466  0.003
Residual    0.1674964              

Fixed effects: x ~ visit1
                Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 10.952459 0.1883601 24 58.14640  0.0000
visit1V4     0.031497 0.2082014 24  0.15128  0.8810
visit1V7    -0.346842 0.1190620 24 -2.91312  0.0076

Correlation:
         (Intr) vst1V4
visit1V4 -0.492       
visit1V7 -0.473  0.090

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.12819289 -0.19660884 -0.06543492  0.17633675  1.01718946 

Number of Observations: 39
Number of Groups: 
           sampleid batch %in% sampleid 
                 13                  13
```

Only intercept model gives a better fit

```
    lme2<-update(lme1,random=~1|sampleid/batch)
     > summary(lme2)
     Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
     Data: newx 
     AIC      BIC    logLik
   53.50052 63.00163 -20.75026

   Random effects:
   Formula: ~1 | sampleid
     (Intercept)
    StdDev: 1.636268e-05

    Formula: ~1 | batch %in% sampleid
     (Intercept)  Residual
    StdDev: 1.632057e-05 0.3869672

   Fixed effects: x ~ visit1 
         Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
  (Intercept)  9.923162 0.1073254 24 92.45866  0.0000
  visit1V4    -0.333890 0.1517810 24 -2.19982  0.0377
  visit1V7    -0.246486 0.1517810 24 -1.62396  0.1174
 Correlation: 
         (Intr) vst1V4
visit1V4 -0.707       
visit1V7 -0.707  0.500

 Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.5208757 -0.5757388  0.2255019  0.7457944  1.2827374 

Number of Observations: 39
Number of Groups: 
           sampleid batch %in% sampleid 
             13                  13 




anova(lme1,lme2)
     Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test   L.Ratio p-value
lme1     1 16 73.15228 98.48859 -20.57614                         
lme2     2  6 53.50052 63.00163 -20.75026 1 vs 2 0.3482341       1
```

My question is about the batch effect.There seems to be no batch effect.Am i correct?

Comment: It is not quite clear what your design is, but I'm trying to guess. `visit1`is time, `batch` has two levels, `sampleid`is the subject, no continuous covariates. And you suspect that batch has a linear effect on the substance level, and try to see how it reacts over visits? If yes, then it does not make much sense to use random effects here, just a simple fixed effects model `x ~ batch + visit1´ would do. If you need random effects, the lme4 package might suit your needs better (nested/crossed effects).

Comment: Doing the experiment in two batches was the limitation.I am interested in just compensating for the batch effect.Why would you call it fixed effect rather than random effect.Just consider it similar to the data collected from two different clinics. Here two batches can be considered a higher level class.

Comment: I would call it a fixed effect because it make no sense to estimate the distribution of the batches, mainly because there only two of them. The linear model in my previous comment compensates for the batch effect. You'd probably get more comments if you documented the structure better, if there is any (as opposed to my guess above).